# Identify the highest and lowest index of a pair of number

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working on temporal data and this question relates to a code [written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57573327/how-to-sum-up-identical-cells-in-a-data-frame) earlier.

```
library(data.table)
Aggregated <- fread("
    act1_1 act1_2 act1_3 act1_4 act1_5
    2        1      3      2    6
    1        2      2      1  1
    1        4      2      2  3
    ")


cols <- names(Aggregated)
n <- length(cols)

vi <- CJ(rn = 1:nrow(Aggregated), len = 2:5, start = 1:n)[

  , end := start + len - 1L][

    end <= n]

dl <- melt(setDT(Aggregated)[, rn := .I], id.vars = "rn", variable.name = "pos", 
           variable.factor = TRUE)[

             , pos := as.integer(pos)][]

result <- dl[vi, on = .(rn, pos >= start, pos <= end), 
             .(rn, values = toString(value), position = toString(cols[x.pos])), 
             by = .EACHI, nomatch = 0L][

               , .(freq = .N), by = .(values, position)]


fin<-result[order(nchar(values), values)]

fin[,summed:=sum(freq), by=values]

fin$sm <- ifelse(duplicated(fin$values) == T, NA, fin$summed)

fin<-fin[!is.na(fin$sm), ]
```

My question how to create another column that returns the start and end of the frequencies :

```
                             freq   summed          Start   End        
5:   2,1    act1_1, act1_2    1      2              act1_1 act1_4
6:   2,1    act1_3, act1_4    1
7:   2,2    act1_2, act1_3    1      2
8:   2,2    act1_3, act1_4    1
```

Example of start number (not from the   Aggregated df): the starting point of the pair of numbers

```
                                freq   summed        Start   End    
 5:  2, 1     act1_1, act1_2    1       1            act1_1   
 6:  2, 2     act1_1  act1_4    1       1            NA
 7:  2, 3     act1_3, act1_4    1       1            NA
 8:  2, 4     act1_2, act1_3    1       1            NA
 9:  2, 7     act1_3, act1_4    1       1            NA
10:  3, 7     act1_5, act1_6    1       1            act1_5
11:  4, 1     act1_5, act1_6    1       2            act1_4
11:  4, 1     act1_7, act1_8    1       NA           NA
12:  4 ,2     act1_4, act1_5    1       1            NA
```

Example of end number the end point of the pair of numbers

```
                              freq   summed           Start   End    
 5:  2, 1     act1_1, act1_2    1       1                    act1_4    
 6:  2, 2     act1_1  act1_4    1       1                    NA
 7:  2, 3     act1_3, act1_4    1       1                    NA
 8:  2, 4     act1_2, act1_3    1       1                    NA
 9:  2, 7     act1_3, act1_4    1       1                    NA
10:  3, 7     act1_5, act1_6    1       1                    act1_6
11:  4, 1     act1_5, act1_6    1       2                    act1_8
11:  4, 1     act1_7, act1_8    1       NA                   NA 
12:  4 ,2     act1_4, act1_5    1       1                    NA
```

Final output:

```
                               freq   summed       Start   End    
 5:  2, 1     act1_1, act1_2    1       1          act1_1   act1_4    
 6:  2, 2     act1_1  act1_4    1       1          NA       NA
 7:  2, 3     act1_3, act1_4    1       1          NA       NA
 8:  2, 4     act1_2, act1_3    1       1          NA       NA
 9:  2, 7     act1_3, act1_4    1       1          NA       NA
10:  3, 7     act1_5, act1_6    1       1          act1_5   act1_6
11:  4, 1     act1_5, act1_6    1       2          act1_4   act1_8
11:  4, 1     act1_7, act1_8    1       NA         NA       NA 
12:  4 ,2     act1_4, act1_5    1       1          NA       NA
```

Comment: Is it values the column that gives the criterion of start and end? If so, why `2,1` has `act1_4` as end, when it has only `act1_1` and `act1_2` or is it only the first number what to look at (in rows >=11, what to look, I gost 3 values using your code)? Could you explain better how to pick the start and end regarding which column? Also, the the start is the `act1_ ...` that has the smaller`...`, and the end the biggest `...`?

Comment: @s_t thanks for your time yes the colums give the criterion for the start and the end.  But the columns I assume should be group by their starting number so for example 1,1 -> 1,2 and 1, ... would form a group that has a specific start and end number; 2,1  , 2,2 2 ,... would form a different group that have different or similar start and end number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not too much clear, but maybe this could be a starting point, using base R and a bit of `dplyr`:

```
# first we need in the dataset a new column, used subsequently
fin$value_short <- substr(fin$values,1,1)

library(dplyr)
# now the dplyr chain 
aggregated <- fin %>%
              # add a column to use subsequently
              mutate(value_short = substr(values,1,1)) %>%
              # split the position column
              separate_rows(position, sep =', ') %>%
              # select useful columns
              select(position,value_short) %>%
              # group
              group_by(value_short) %>%
              # calculate the start and the end
              summarise(start = paste0('act1_', min(as.numeric(substr(position,6,6)))),
                        end = paste0('act1_', max(as.numeric(substr(position,6,6)))))
```

With this result:

```
aggregated 
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  value_short start  end   
  <chr>       <chr>  <chr> 
1 1           act1_1 act1_5
2 2           act1_1 act1_5
3 3           act1_3 act1_5
4 4           act1_2 act1_5

# Now, let's join the aggregated to the original data:
fin_aggr <- fin %>% left_join(aggregated)

# remove the dupes
fin_aggr$start <- ifelse(duplicated(fin_aggr$value_short), NA, fin_aggr$start)
fin_aggr$end <- ifelse(duplicated(fin_aggr$value_short), NA, fin_aggr$end)

# remove the useless column
fin_aggr <- fin_aggr[,-6]
```

With this result:

```
fin_aggr

         values                               position freq summed sm  start    end
1           1, 1                         act1_4, act1_5    1      1  1 act1_1 act1_5
2           1, 2                         act1_1, act1_2    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
3           1, 3                         act1_2, act1_3    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
4           1, 4                         act1_1, act1_2    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
5           2, 1                         act1_1, act1_2    1      2  2 act1_1 act1_5
6           2, 2                         act1_2, act1_3    1      2  2   <NA>   <NA>
7           2, 3                         act1_4, act1_5    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
8           2, 6                         act1_4, act1_5    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
9           3, 2                         act1_3, act1_4    1      1  1 act1_3 act1_5
10          4, 2                         act1_2, act1_3    1      1  1 act1_2 act1_5
11       1, 2, 2                 act1_1, act1_2, act1_3    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
12       1, 3, 2                 act1_2, act1_3, act1_4    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
13       1, 4, 2                 act1_1, act1_2, act1_3    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
14       2, 1, 1                 act1_3, act1_4, act1_5    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
15       2, 1, 3                 act1_1, act1_2, act1_3    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
16       2, 2, 1                 act1_2, act1_3, act1_4    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
17       2, 2, 3                 act1_3, act1_4, act1_5    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
18       3, 2, 6                 act1_3, act1_4, act1_5    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
19       4, 2, 2                 act1_2, act1_3, act1_4    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
20    1, 2, 2, 1         act1_1, act1_2, act1_3, act1_4    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
21    1, 3, 2, 6         act1_2, act1_3, act1_4, act1_5    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
22    1, 4, 2, 2         act1_1, act1_2, act1_3, act1_4    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
23    2, 1, 3, 2         act1_1, act1_2, act1_3, act1_4    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
24    2, 2, 1, 1         act1_2, act1_3, act1_4, act1_5    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
25    4, 2, 2, 3         act1_2, act1_3, act1_4, act1_5    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
26 1, 2, 2, 1, 1 act1_1, act1_2, act1_3, act1_4, act1_5    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
27 1, 4, 2, 2, 3 act1_1, act1_2, act1_3, act1_4, act1_5    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
28 2, 1, 3, 2, 6 act1_1, act1_2, act1_3, act1_4, act1_5    1      1  1   <NA>   <NA>
```